# A simple and multi-platform way to use TCP sockets in truly full-duplex way

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm developing a microservice in C++, and for my particular case I decided to go with the TCP sockets for the communication between the core system and my microservice.

My goals with regard to the transport layer are:

1. As few bottlenecks as possible
2. Support for both Linux (as target platform) and Windows (for testing purposes)
3. As simple an implementation as possible

I was planning to go with **boost.asio**, but its socket implementation isn't
thread-safe, i.e. I wouldn't be able to read and write from the same socket simultaneously, even though the system-level socket I/O would've allowed it due to the full-duplex nature of TCP.

So, if I want the most simple code and the least abstraction fuss, what are my options with regard to the socket libraries?

Comment: "*I wouldn't be able to read and write from the same socket simultaneously, even though the system-level socket I/O would've allowed it*" - that was addressed in [boost 1.37.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_37_0.html): "*Synchronous read, write, accept and connect operations are now thread safe (meaning that it is now permitted to perform concurrent synchronous operations on an individual socket, if supported by the OS).*"

Comment: Check [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)

Comment: I've had good luck using non-blocking sockets, managed via select(); it gives me full-duplex event-driven I/O and is supported by just about every OS with a TCP stack.  (My networking/messaging library is here in case you'd like to see an implementation of it:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/ )

Comment: @RemyLebeau wish you posted that as a separate and more detailed answer, because the SO posts on the same topic from '09 and '11 are probably misleading by now... Also, how would you comment on boost 1.66.0 thread safety description of `ip::tcp::socket`: "Shared objects: Unsafe". Would using the same socket object between two threads, one reader and one writer, qualify as sharing?